# It can be shown that the multiplicative group $(\mathbb{Z}_{10})^\times$ is cyclic. To which group is it isomorphic?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, totient-function

It can be show that the multiplicative group $(\mathbb{Z}_{10})^\times$ is cyclic. To which group is it isomorphic?

**What I have tried:**

I have calculated the order of $(\mathbb{Z}_{10})^\times$ to be 4. Hence I think it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{4}$.

Would someone be able to verify if my answer is correct?

Thank you for taking the time to respond to my question.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  You are correct that the order of $(\mathbb Z_{10})^\times$ is $4$, and there is only one cyclic group of order $4$ up to isomorphism

Comment: More generally, there is one cyclic group of any finite order

Comment: You might also want to look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $(\mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}), \times)$ has 4 elements in it. So it is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}, +)$, indeed any cyclic group with 4 elements. Note that for each $m$ there is exactly one cyclic group of order $m$, up to group isomorphism.

Meanwhile to show that $(\mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}), \times)$ is indeed cyclic, note that 3 generates every element in this group.

Comment: Thus, **if it is, in fact, cyclic**, it must be isomorphic to $(\Bbb Z /4 \Bbb Z, +)$.  The original post doesn't demonstrate that the group is cyclic, and there are plenty of examples of similar multiplicative groups -- $(\Bbb Z / 8 \Bbb Z, \cdot)^*$, for example -- that aren't cyclic so there really is something to show here.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that the order of $(\mathbb Z_{10})^\times$ is $4$,

and there is only one cyclic group of order $4$ up to isomorphism.

The set of elements of $(\mathbb Z_{10})^\times$ is $\{[1],[3],[7],[9]\}$, and

you could make the isomorphism from  $(\mathbb Z_{10})^\times$ to $\mathbb Z_4$ explicit

by mapping $[1]\mapsto0$, $[3]\mapsto1$, $[9]\mapsto2$, and $[7]\mapsto3$, for example.

Answer (score 0):

The order of $\Bbb Z_n^\times$ is $\varphi(n)$, where $\varphi$ is the totient function.  $\varphi(10)=4$.

You can check that $3$ has order four in $\Bbb Z_{10}^\times$.  Because $3^2\equiv9, 3^3\equiv7\bmod10$.  That is, $3$ is a *primitive element $\bmod10$*.

Thus we have the cyclic group of order $4$.

Comment: with multiplicative groups do we always check the order of 3 in the group?

Comment: @Rox, if your group wasn't cyclic, then it would be $\Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_2$ and all its nonidentity elements would have order $2$.

Comment: No. In general a primitive could be any element of the group of units, other than one.  Or there might not be a primitive, which occurs when the group of units isn't cyclic.